# Proper way of connecting to third party Outlook calendars

Tags: azure, outlook, entra-id, microsoft, azure-web-apps

We are doing an Outlook integration where we have an app for meeting rooms and we want to connect to other companies meeting rooms which were configured in Outlook. If someone reserves a meeting room through Outlook, we get updated. If someone reserves a meeting room through our app, we check the availability in client's Outlook and (if free) we reserve the resource.

At this point we kind of struggle to understand which approach is the best. Namely, what is the best way to connect our app to client's calendar. We talked with an Azure admin who said that he could do that through the Enterprise Applications section, but he advised us to use an account created by them for us to have this connection.

From out standpoint, this is not very maintainable, as we would need to have and account per client. We would prefer to have just our app in the Azure store. Is it possible and how can we do that to configure Azure to restrict our app's access to only the meeting rooms' calendars?

Comment: If using Graph this may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure this question might be better suited at the Azure collective

Comment: This question was actually removed from Stack Overflow and suggested to be asked here. (:

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing

See here you can request an app

---

The advice for an account is very bad, an enterprise application is the right way. You could also maybe create some automation which automatically creates an enterprise app in the customers tenant. Maybe some PowerShell.

---

I do think that customers have privacy concerns if you connect to all calendars, so you need to scope that to meeting rooms.

Comment: As I have learnt later, there is no possibility to scope Enterprise Applications in Azure. And there is an option to do that with accounts. This is why one of the admins told me its the preferable solution.